# Are two circular buffers equal? (While ignoring shift)

Tags: algorithm

I have two circular buffers -- how can I tell if one is just a shift of another?

For example with `B1 = 1,1,2,1,8,1,5,7`, `B2 = 2,1,8,1,5,7,1,1` we can say that B1 and B2 are equal, because I can rotate one of them to get the other.

What is the best algorithm to test this equality? Obvious test is in `O(n^2)` (just compare the buffers - in `n` steps - starting in each of their `n` element) but I believe I've seen a linear time algorithm. Can you please point me to it?

Comment: Don't you know the head or the tail of the two buffers?

Comment: Are the number of elements in the buffers same?

Comment: @smk if they aren't, then just a simple size comparison would resolve the issue. I guess we're safe to assure that they are of same size.

Comment: I think searching about circular permutation would be a good.

Comment: find the longest common sub-array between both buffers, and the rest is easy to figure out. It can be done in linear time. Check this for more details http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `B1` and `B2` have the same length, your question is equivalent to asking "is `B2` a substring of `B1 + B1`" (`B1` concatenated with itself).

For example: 4-element string is a rotation of `1234` if and only if it is a substring of `12341234`.

Checking if one string is a substring of another can be done in linear time using [KMP algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

Comment: The Z-algorithm is also another alternative, but maybe simpler to code and understand (for some people).

Comment: but that still results in a `O(n^2)` solution

Comment: @CaldasGSM, how so? Checking lengths - `O(1)`. Duplicating string - `O(n)`, KMP/Z-algorithm - `O(2n) = O(n)`.

Comment: I think I've seen something else than KMP. The algorithm I have in mind did the same concatenation trick and then did something like start from the smallest elements. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if your buffer is of integers, I was thinking that maybe you could use the fact that addition as the commutative property `(a+b == b+a)`
that means that the start of the list doesn't matter. but on the other hand nether the order of items `(1+2+3+4) = (3+1+2+4)` so to make sure the items are in proper order we may associate them in pairs or trios. to better ensure a chaining order.. `(12+23+34+41)` or something like this..

```
var B1 = [1,1,2,1,8,1,5,7]
var B2 = [2,1,8,1,5,7,1,1]
var B3 = [2,1,8,1,5,7,1,4]

function checksum(buff)
{
    var sum = 0
    for(var i = 0 ; i < buff.length;i++)
    {
        var a  = buff[i];
        var b  = buff[(i+1)%buff.length];
        var c  = buff[(i+2)%buff.length];
        var n = ((a*100) + (b * 10) + c);
        sum += n;
    }
    return sum;
}
console.log(checksum(B1) == checksum(B2))//true
console.log(checksum(B1) == checksum(B3))//false
```

this is a "order sensitive" circular checksum

but like every hash functions there will be collisions and false positives so you will still need a secondary method of comparison..

don't know if i'm on the right track.. hope someone can help to make it better or totally disprove..